# How to attach a virtual hard disk using VBoxManage?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

What is the best method for setting the virtual hard drive (VDI) of the primary controller for an existing virtual machine?

Does the syntax change if the VDI is really a child differencing disk of some other parent disk?  Do you need to attach the parent VDI and then the child VDI in some way?

Situation:

I have an existing VM --- I want to replace the hard drive it uses to boot - with either another normal virtual HD or possibly a differencing disk.  Can this be done with VBoxManage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should do it for a virtual hard drive.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm winxp-web-dev --hda "/home/vbox/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/my_new_disk.vdi"
```

(That is how I do it when I create vm's from the console)

Comment: I think this is not valid way to done. While I try your suggestion, I get `VBoxManage: error: Unknown option: -hda` error.

Comment: Should be double minuses there. (Worked on 4.1.6)

Answer (score 29):

Pretty old question but here is how I do it:

```
VBoxManage storageattach my-vm-name \
                         --storagectl "SATA Controller" \
                         --device 0 \
                         --port 0 \
                         --type hdd \
                         --medium /path/to/my-new.vdi
```

This assumes you want to replace the old disk.

If you just want to add another disk use another port. For example: use port 1 if you already have another disk on port 0.

Also note that you could also add disks (or CD ISO images) to "IDE Controller".

Answer (score 3):

You need first add de contoller on your vm machine:

```
vboxmanage storagectl YourVMNameOrID --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAHCI --portcount 1 --bootable on
```

and then attach the virtual disk image to the storage controller:

```
vboxmanage storageattach YourVMNameOrID --storagectl "SATA Controller" --device 0 --port 0 --type hdd --medium YourVirtualDiskImage.vdi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to @calas with a VM managed by vagrant (run in VM's folder and replace `sandbox_default_` with your VM name prefix):

```
VBoxManage storageattach `VBoxManage list vms | grep \"sandbox_default_ | awk '{print $2;}'` --storagectl SATA --port 0 --type hdd --medium box-disk1.vmdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it though VBoxManage, I've always changed it through the GUI after using CloneHD, you answer may be in the [VBoxManage Manuel](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful for anyone else working with a BootCamp partition that you have to make a new .vmdk for each boot, I had to do this in order to attach the image and avoid the annoying UUID mismatch problem:

Disconnect the medium from the virtual machine
VBoxManage storageattach YourVMNameHere --storagectl "IDE" --device 0 --port 0 --type hdd --medium none

That way it doesn't complain when you remove the medium
VBoxManage closemedium disk /path/to/your/medium.vmdk

Then when you attach the recreated medium you don't get checksum errors
VBoxManage storageattach YourVMNameHere --storagectl "IDE" --device 0 --port 0 --type hdd --medium /path/to/your/medium.vmdk